# Is there forEach-like function in JavaScript, but which returns only index, but not object and index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I wan't to know, is there any function in JavaScript, which just iterates over an object and returns an index. For example:

`[1, 2, 3].iterate(index => /* do smth */)`

If there's no such function, why? I think it may be just another way of representing `for` loop, and it has it's place.

EDIT:

To notice, i know that we can declare our own `iterate` function, the question is **is there any like** and if not **why it doesn't exist**

EDIT 2:

I know there is `forEach` function, but it gives a callBack with `obj, index, array`, so we always have to declare some `obj`. In this case you need to ignore `obj` which is an unnecessary operation.

`[1, 2, 3].forEach( (obj, i) => { console.log(i) }) //we don't need an obj`

So here we ignore `obj`. It HAS a place in memory and DOESN'T fly somewhere in clouds. Ignoring `obj` and using a simple `forEach` is not an answer, please stop answering with default `forEach`.

Comment: Have you looked at the ```forEach``` approach? You could also do ```Object.keys``` and  iterate over that?

Comment: you mean array ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Right.

Comment: The `Object.keys()` function applied to an array will pass the successive index values to the callback function. Of course `.forEach()` and really *all* the other Array iteration functions, in one way or another, also pass the key/index.

Comment: There is such a function. It's called `forEach`. You just have to use the second function parameter in your callback. `[1, 2, 3].forEach((_, index) => /* do smth */)`

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V Yes, but `forEach` gives us an object and index, so if i don't need object i must ignore it. That is a little bit frustrating, because it's an unnecessary operation of assumption.

Comment: There is also `array.map()`.  `[1, 2, 3].map((item, index) => /* do smth */)`

Comment: I don't think such function exists, since iterating through indexes is the same as iterating from 0 to array.length, I can hardly think of a use case for that.
Array.[map | foreach](function(item, index) { ... }), you can use it in your use case

Comment: jQuery's `.each()` passes the index as first argument.

Comment: It’s hard to see how ignoring a parameter counts as an operation.

Comment: Given that an index is used to access an element in the array, saying "we don't need the object" seems short sighted.

Comment: _"Why doesn't [programming language] have [niche feature I desperately need and could easily substitute with something of my own]?"_ is rarely a constructive question and almost always impossible to answer.

Comment: "it's an unnecessary operation of assumption" is a weird take on what the method does.

Comment: @JLRishe I am just asking about a function which goes through an array like `forEach` but doesn't make me do this freaking `forEach((_, index)` and ignore that `_`

Comment: Just use a for/loop.

Comment: What's so "difficult" on ignoring something? O.o

Comment: @Andy I am trying to get a functional-style code, so i try to avoid for/loop's.

Comment: @V.Dalechin Here you go: `Array.prototype.iterateIndexes = function (cb) { this.forEach((_, i) => cb(i)); }`

Comment: @Andreas because it's not proper way to programm something by just **ignoring** some value you don't need but which uses memory.

Comment: @JLRishe that may be an answer but it still has this value-ignoring feature `_`.

Comment: @V.Dalechin Ok, here's your answer: (1) _Does such a function exist?_ - No, no such function exists. `Object.keys()` comes close, but it shouldn't be used for this purpose. (2) _Why doesn't such a function exist?_ - Who the heck knows? Feel free to try and dig up some record of the language designers declaring why they _didn't_ include such a feature. I doubt anybody else is going to. If you need it so badly, you're more than welcome to write your own function that doesn't "ignore" the array elements. It should only take about 5-6 lines of code.

Comment: @JLRishe Finally you've got my idea.

Comment: @V.Dalechin It's absolutely "proper" to use `forEach` in this case, and to ignore the function arguments you don't care about. This is why JavaScript provides only `forEach`, and not an equivalent function to iterate over indices. This isn't a problem with JavaScript, it's a problem with your assumptions, and you should abandon this idea that it's somehow harmful to ignore the first argument to your callback. What you *shouldn't* do here is use `Object.keys` if you're concerned about memory usage. For an array of N elements, you're needlessly creating a whole second array of N elements.

Comment: @V.Dalechin If you _really, really_ want to iterate the indices of an array without "ignoring" its values, you can use this helper function. It's infinitely better than using `Object.keys` for this: `function iterateIndices(arr, cb) { if (!(arr && arr.length > 0 && typeof cb === 'function')) { return; } for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) { cb(i); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you essentially trying to only get the indexes within the array, if so, you can use the first approach that you can see in this implementation, if you *may* want to get the keys and the values, then you can use the `forEach` approach that I've also provided.

## Explained

As you may have guessed by now, using the `Object.keys` function, that will return an array of keys on the object that has been passed into the function, in this scenario, an array has just numbers as keys, therefore it returns an array of indexes, you can then loop over that array if you wish.

This is the gist of what's happening with the first approach that I've provided.

### Note

As @Szab has said, if the Array object has been manipulated in some way so that it may or may not have extra properties, then this solution *may* not perform as expected. But in my personal opinion, you shouldn't be doing that in the first place, but it's still a good point to take note!

### Edit

Another solution you could do is make use of the solution provided by @JLRishe where you add some function to `Array.prototype`, this way you can use a `forEach` like approach also.

```js
const array = ['fds', 'dsa', 'dsfsd'];

// A solution by @JLRishe
Array.prototype.forEachIndex = function(cb) {
  this.forEach((_, i) => cb(i));
};


// Demo.
Object.keys(array).forEach(i => console.log(i));
array.forEach((i, index) => console.log(i, index));
array.forEachIndex(i => console.log(i));
```

Comment: Please note that the `Object.keys` approach might produce incorrect results if for any reason the array object was extended with any additional property.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what i was asking about. I don't know why people are getting mad and votedown my question. I DON'T WANT `forEach`!!!

Comment: @V.Dalechin how are you expecting to iterate over an array, without using forEach or a for loop?

Comment: @V.Dalechin Don't worry about it, I don't really know why, but I've been receiving down votes on my answer?! Haha...

Comment: This answer is worse than `forEach` for memory usage, which is what OP seems to be worried about. `Object.keys` creates a completely *new array*, and fills it *copies* of all the numeric indicies from the original array. If you have an array of 100,000 items, `forEach` involves virtually no overhead. If you use `Object.keys(x).forEach`, you're making a *new* 100,000 item array full of 100,000 strings, just so you can start iterating over the original array.

Comment: @meagar wow... that's really bad

Comment: @V.Dalechin Yes, it's really bad, arguably the worst way to iterate over the indices of an array if you're concerned about memory usage. You should be using a `for` loop or `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: @meagar thanks for an explanation

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach((value, index) => console.log(index + " " + value));
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `forEach` works similarly. It passes three arguments into the provided callback - the first one is the current element, the second one is its index and the third one is the whole array.

```
let example = [1, 2, 3];
example.forEach((item, index) => { 
    console.log(`Item ${item}, index ${index}`); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(function(element, index) {
  console.log(index, element);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but if i need only index i'll have to ignore `element` which i don't need to even exist.